# Determine the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces on the right-handed side of this Whitehead tower?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces

What and how to determine the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces on the right-handed side of this Whitehead tower?

Namely, how do we know
$$
K(Z_2,1)?, \quad K(Z_2,2)?, \quad K(Z,4)?
$$

Naively -- in each step the lowest homotopy group is killed by the map into the Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.

- BSO is the homotopy fibre of the map from BO given by the first Stiefel Whitney class $w_1$. But why $K(Z_2,1)$?
- BSpin is the homotopy fibre of the map from BSO given by the second Stiefel Whitney class $w_2$. But why $K(Z_2,2)$?
- BO⟨8⟩ is the homotopy fibre of the map from BSpin given by half of the first Pontryagin class $1/2 p_1$. But why $K(Z,4)$?

[image]

Comment: Because, at each stage, you're attaching cells to kill off all the homotopy above the bottommost degree. Play with the induced long exact sequence in homotopy groups for each fiber sequence to see that, at each stage, the resulting Eilenberg-Mac Lane space will have its nontrivial homotopy group be the appropriate homotopy group of BO. And the homotopy groups of BO in low degrees are as you described, by real Bott periodicity.